# Windows: blurry texts?

Tags: windows, fonts

I had to reinstall Windows and now labels usually blurry compared to my earlier system.

Also it seems to have problems generating windows correctly, see this below image for demo:

[image]

Corner of titlebar is mis-aligned, and all the labels are a bit blurry.

I'm using external monitors via DisplayLink.

Windows is updated:

```
Windows 10 Pro, Version 21H2 (build 19044.1645)
Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4170.0
```

Windows was "reset" with the advnaced tools because it was unable to boot.

I feel it doesn't use the same fonts as it used before by default. This is how I see this text in the editor:

[image]

Do we have any idea on what can be missing?

Comment: Looks like display scaling is active (not at 100%). Is that intentional?

Comment: Definitely scaling, as @DanielB has said. Also, try toggling ClearType.

Comment: Run the Clear Type tool to see if that makes text clearer.  Within limits, clear type works for reasonable scaling settings.

Comment: 100% is used, no scaling were selected. Cleartype tool I used, and actually rebooted, which eliminated the issue from the window. However, the text which I'm typing into the textbox when asking a new question here, is still displayed like shown on my image.

Comment: I have the same problem (almost identical screenshot). I'm accessing a Windows 2019 VM over RDP from Windows 10 22H2. Local and remote system is at 100% scaling. The "Fix blurry text" option in Windows (bot local and remote) is set. Local windows are not blurry, only the remote one.

Comment: FYI: my problem also disappeared after rebooting the remote PC. Weird.

Answer (score -1):

First make sure your graphics aka video card drivers and installed an up to date.

Then you need to change the resolution of your screen to match the native resolution of your monitor.  Using non-native resolution risk blurry fonts.

Windows usually auto-detects the resolutions the monitor is capable of through EDID from the monitor.  Normally you need to slide the resolution slider to the max setting because the max setting is **usually** native resolution.

If your monitor supports virtual resolutions or internal scaling then the max resolution might be wrong.

Comment: His screenshot (displayed on your monitor )is blurry too, so it is not a monitor resolution problem.